# Disable select a certificate for authentication pop up on IIS and Next JS

Tags: ssl, iis, deployment, next.js, next-auth

After deploying a webapp created using Next JS to a windows server (2019) and using IIS for reverse proxy via rewrite URL everything works very well except the authentication of the program. I used Next Auth for frontend authentication, but now I keep on getting strange messages asking to select a certificate for authentication. This also tends to happen multiple times. I know a few people recommend going on IIS and under SSL Settings and select ignore client certificates, but then my authorization and sign in does not work at all. It causes the sign in to not work at all as well as having weird sessions. I could open the website in a private window and it would open a logged in session. So the question is am I looking at the IIS part wrong or the Next JS part wrong? Because by having client certificates accepted it displays confusing pop ups and with it ignored NEXT Auth won't work. Why would client certificates even be necessary for Next auth to work? Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can refer to:https://forums.iis.net/t/1239295.aspx